# grub rescue with dual boot 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have dual booted Ubuntu from a usb. I installed it, and at first it was going slow. I then rebooted the whole system and tried to log in. again, was moving slow (move mouse and cursor would lag about 10 seconds before moving. Now, I get the grub rescue- no partition found, and when I boot from usb to try Ubuntu, it moves slow and I cannot do anything. how do I get windows back, and save my computer. "windows 7 dual booted with latest Ubuntu 14 lts.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs when the Boot, probably it will present the rescue boot, if so try the following:
Run the ls command,

> ls

will appear:

```
 (hd0) (hd0, m ..) (hd0, ....) etc.
```

With this information, you will execute the command:

> ls (hd0)

If you see the error message unknown filesystem, do the same command by:

> ls (hd0,1)

If you continue giving error, continue changing the number after the comma (hd0,2 ...) until:

```
 ./ ../ / Lost + found / selinux etc / media / ...
```

And so it goes.

Let's imagine that our file system is on the partition hd0,2. Give a Enter and we will begin to correct the error.

Enter the following commands:

> set prefix = (hd0,2) / boot / grub # Hit enter
>
> set root = (hd0,2)
>
> insmod (hd0,2) # If /boot/grub/i386-pc/linux.mod der error, take the i386-pc leave like this: ... / grub / linux.mod
>
> linux / vmlinuz root = / dev / sda2 ro # If yours is, for example, (hd0,3) is your sda3. Detail: the ro is part of the command.
>
> initrd /initrd.img
>
> boot

After all the above process, to boot the system, please administrator mode and run the command:

> $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub

Reinstalling GRUB, your problem will be solved completely.

Then install the Grub Customizer

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa: danielrichter2007 / grub-customizer
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

It's pretty intuitive to organize your boot

Regards